# Android shared preferences error while accessing data without internet

Tags: android, json, android-sharedpreferences

i am trying to make app where data is save on server and i am fetching that data in my list view when i access online then i can access the data but when i add
shared preferences in my code and then try to access data then i can't able to access data following is my code.
MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ListView listView;
Button button;
String Url="my server name is here";
ArrayList<User> arrayList;
//MyFile myFile
public static String SP_FILE_NAME="sp_Listview";
//SharedPreferences spfile;
MySharedPrefLib mySharedPrefLib;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    arrayList = new ArrayList<User>();
    //myFile = new MyFile(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);


    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (isNetworkAvailable() == true) {

                StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,Url, new Response.Listener<String>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Log.d("mytag", "Response" + response);

                        mySharedPrefLib.sharedpreferences.edit().putString("response", response).commit();

                        fillResult(response);


                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.d("Mytag", "Error" + error);

                    }

                });
                RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
                requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
            } else if (mySharedPrefLib.checkSharedPrefs("response")) {

                fillResult(mySharedPrefLib.getPref("response"));

            }
        }

    });
}

private void fillResult(String response) {
    try {
        JSONArray JSONArray = new JSONArray(response);

        //   myFile.sharePref("response"+response).commit;

       // arrayList = new ArrayList<User>();
        for (int i = 0; i < JSONArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = JSONArray.getJSONObject(i);
            User user = new User();

            user.setID(jsonObject.getString("ID"));
            user.setName(jsonObject.getString("Name"));
            user.setEmail(jsonObject.getString("Email"));
            user.setPassword(jsonObject.getString("Password"));

            arrayList.add(user);

        }

        UserAdapter<User> userAdapter = new UserAdapter(getApplicationContext(), arrayList);
        listView.setAdapter(userAdapter);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
    return isConnected;
}
```

}

MySharedPrefLib.java

```
public class MySharedPrefLib {

Context context;
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;

public MySharedPrefLib(Context context){
    this.context=context;
    sharedpreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(MainActivity.SP_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
}

public void saveSharedPrefs(String user_id, String user_name, String user_email){

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("ID", user_id);
    editor.putString("Name", user_name);
    editor.putString("Email", user_email);
    editor.putString("Password", user_email);


    editor.commit();
}

public  String getPref(String key) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(MainActivity.SP_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return preferences.getString(key, null);
}

public void clearSharedPrefs(){
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(MainActivity.SP_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
    editor.clear();
    editor.commit();
}

public boolean checkSharedPrefs(String key){
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(MainActivity.SP_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if(sharedPrefs.contains(key)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

instead of this  i am adding two more class which is user.java and useradpter
follwing is my errorlog

Error Log

```
09-21 12:21:40.039 19716-19716/com.example.mahadev.listview2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           Process: com.example.mahadev.listview2, PID: 19716
                                                                           java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'android.content.SharedPreferences com.example.mahadev.listview2.MySharedPrefLib.sharedpreferences' on a null object reference
                                                                               at com.example.mahadev.listview2.MainActivity$1$1.onResponse(MainActivity.java:58)
                                                                               at com.example.mahadev.listview2.MainActivity$1$1.onResponse(MainActivity.java:52)
                                                                               at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:60)
                                                                               at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
                                                                               at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
```

error come on here

```
  mySharedPrefLib.sharedpreferences.edit().putString("response", response).commit();
```

And here

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,Url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
```

Any Suggestion are welcome .

Comment: You have not initialize  mySharedPrefLib.sharedpreferences.

Comment: Thanks its working now

Answer (score 0):

Add line

> mySharedPrefLib = new MySharedPrefLib(context);

that will initialize that is the only problem.

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to initialize mySharedPrefLib

add this **mySharedPrefLib = new MySharedPrefLib(this);**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    arrayList = new ArrayList<User>();
    .
    .
    .
    mySharedPrefLib = new MySharedPrefLib(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add following line

```
mySharedPrefLib = this.getSharedPreferences(
      "com.example.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

where `"com.example.app"` will be your package name.

before

```
mySharedPrefLib.sharedpreferences.edit().putString("response", response).commit();
```

as your `mySharedPrefLib` is not initialised it't throwing `NullPointerException`